# k means clustering limit?

Tags: r, k-means

I'm doing a kmeans clustering to analyze my data. So far Its working perfectly.
This is my code so far:

```
library(Ckmeans.1d.dp)
file=read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
attach(file)
sortfile=file[order(normalized),]
results=Ckmeans.1d.dp(normalized,3)
plot(results)
```

Now, I'm able to get the clusters,and the centers, but I'm more interested in getting the "limits" of the cluster. Not the maximum value in one cluster among the data I used, but the limits of the cluster I have now. Is that possible? how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K-Means labels points based on their closest centroids (cluster centers). So the "limits" between clusters (called the decision boundary) are the points which have at least two different centroids as their closest centroids (e.g. have the exact same distance from them).

For example in 2D, for each point in the plane calculate it's closest centroids. If it has more than one (e.g. at least two centroids are at minimal distance from it), then it is part of the decision boundary.